# Typographic rules and optimal margins

Tags: spacing, margins, typography

I've read all around the web that the "optimal" number of characters per line is about 70 (exact numbers change a bit according to the one who writes but most of times the range is something like 65-75), but I actually couldn't find the original source for these numbers. I expect they are the results of studies that show how these numbers results in a better feeling for the reader and/or makes the text statistically easier to read and so on.

Could somebody point me to the studies that support these numbers? I made a quick search but I couldn't find anything meaningful and/or scientifically relevant.

Comment: It's probably covered in this doc by Peter Wilson https://ctan.org/pkg/memdesign, it might stem from the elements of typography by Robert bringhurst, not sure where he got them though

Comment: Peter Wilson states that "experiments have shown that...", with no  explicit reference. Ironically, he uses lines of up to 100 characters. Maybe I just need to check more carefully. Tomorrow I'll take a look also at Bringhurst's book. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Depends on the audience.  For small children and management, use big letters and lots of colors.

Comment: Peter has good reason to do so, in a doc like that and the memoir manual, the doc gets significantly longer if you have to keep lines under 70 chars

Answer (score 2):

**Well, at last there is no "the one and only typographical rule" for typesetting.** What you should do depends on the result you want: a book, a letter, a memo, a flyer, etc. have different "typographic rules" to get well layouted results.

At last, there is no study -- as far as I know -- but there are several books available describing what one can do to get a good typography.

In german you can for example read "Lesetypografie" and "Detailtypografie" or the english book of Bringhurst "Elements of typography" ...

If you can read german you can read the [german article by Marcus Kohm, Satzspiegelkonstruktionen im Vergleich](https://archiv.dante.de/tex/typographie/satzspiegel/) or you can read chapter 2 of the manual of KOMA-Script "Calculating the Page Layout with typearea" (`texdoc scrguien.pdf` on your terminal/console with installed KOMA-Script).

They show you how you can build pretty layouts with different methods. This methods are used in typographic results of today, you have to choose one of them, depending on what you want ...

Gutenberg developed and used this main rules to build good typographical books when he was printing the first bible, based on the knowledge of writing good looking books by hand.